# Why DSpace webapps doesn't have .war?

Tags: dspace

I'm trying to install DSpace on Windows following [documentation](https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSPACE/Installing+DSpace+on+Windows).I have  to Copy the .war Web application files from C:\dspace\webapps and there aren't any. I tried to import project to Eclipse to make .war, but it didn't work. Can somebody help me?

Comment: WHat do you mean by 'it did not work'? You got an error? Nothing happenend? It crashed?

Answer (score 0):

Ant update or fresh-install copy the compiled webapps to the dspace.install.dir variable setted into dspace.cfg (or build.properties, or local.cfg depending of the DSpace version you ar)
You must copy the desired directories into tomcat webapps dir. An interfaz (xmlui or jspui) and solr is mandatory.